# polymer 1 the observer is not fired when the one property of an object in a behavior is modified

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

When selectedWidget.id value is changed the observer doesn't detected the change.

This observer:

observers: ['functionOberveId(selectedWidget.id)'],

The code hola-mundo.html is:

```html
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="./hidding-behaviour.html">
<dom-module id="hola-mundo">
 <style>
  h1{
   color: blue;
  }
 </style>
 <template>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <button on-click="changeValuebahviourId">changeValuebahviourId</button>
  <button on-click="showValuebehaviourId">showValuebahviourId</button>
  
 </template>

 <script>
  Polymer({
   is: "hola-mundo",
   behaviors: [Hidding],
   observers: ['functionOberveId(selectedWidget.id)'],
   
   
   functionOberveId: function(){
    console.log("the observer is working fine")
    console.log("the id value in behaviour is: " + this.selectedWidget.id)
   },
   
   changeValuebahviourId: function(){
    this.selectedWidget.id= (this.selectedWidget.id +1)
   }, 
   showValuebehaviourId: function(){
    console.log("the id value in behaviour is: " + this.selectedWidget.id)
   }, 
  });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

The code hidding-behaviour.html is:

```js
<script>
    Hidding = {        
        properties:{
            selectedWidget: {
                type: Object,
                value: {
                    item: null,
                    id: 0,
                },
            },
        },
        
    }
</script>
```

The index.html code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Prueba de index</title>
 <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
 <link rel="import" href="./hola-mundo.html">
</header>
<body>

 <hola-mundo></hola-mundo>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the observer isn't shooted when we press the button "changeValuebahviourId"?

I would appreciate help in this I have been reviewing it for a long time and I can not find a solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer needs to know that something changed so insted of calling

```
this.selectedWidget.id= (this.selectedWidget.id +1)
```

Use this:

```
this.set('selectedWidget.id', this.selectedWidget.id +1);
```

[Documentation polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system)